# In how many different ways can I call a function

Tags: c++, function

In how many ways can I call this function, I found this question in one book and I was like 1 but I'm not sure, I think I can call it just once because, it has 3 integer parameters so that's the only way, I guess. The given answers wear (1, 2, 3 or 4) ways to call the Function.

```
int Volume (int x, int y=0, int z=3){ return x+y+z;}
```

What's the correct answer?

Comment: You have one required parameter and 2 optional parameters....

Comment: @John3136 oh yeah, but does that change the answer to 2?

Comment: What about `((int (*)()) Volume)();`

Comment: @Wyck You're casting a function pointer to the wrong type. I'd be surprised if that wasn't undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways.

Example :

```
volume(3) //x = 3, y = 0, z = 3

volume(3,4) // x = 3, y = 4, z = 3

volume(3,4,5) // x = 3, y = 4, z = 5
```